# Basis of vector spaces in perfect pairing

Tags: vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vector-space-isomorphism, dual-spaces

Let $R$ be a field, and let $M$ and $N$ be $d$-dimensional $R$-vectorspaces. Suppose we have a pairing:
\begin{align*}
M \times N \rightarrow R\\
m \times n \mapsto \langle m,n \rangle
\end{align*}
which is a perfect pairing, meaning in this case that $\Phi_1$ is an isomorphism.
\begin{align*}
\Phi_1: M \rightarrow N^* \\
m \mapsto (n \mapsto \langle m,n \rangle)
\end{align*}
This also means that $M \simeq N^* \simeq N$. Suppose we now have a basis for $M$, say $\{m_1,..,m_d\}$, then this must correspond to a basis $\{n_1,..,n_d\}$ under these isomorphisms. What I am now wondering is what we can see about the pairing over two corresponding basis elements, so what can we say about $\langle n_i,m_i \rangle$.

More specifically, my problem is about $R$-linear operators $T_N$ on $N$ and $T_M$ on $M$ that work on both $M$ and $N$ and that 'respect the duality' or are 'compatible', in the sense that:
\begin{align*}
\langle T_M(m),n \rangle = \langle m,T_N(n) \rangle
\end{align*}
Suppose now the basis elements $m_i$ is are eigenvectors for the operator $T_M$, so $T(m_i)=\lambda_i m_i$ for all $1 \leq i \leq d$, can we show that the corresponding basis for $N$ is also an eigenbasis for $T_N$, i.e. $T_N(n_i)=\lambda_i(n_i)$? I have been trying to figure this out, but I keep coming back to the first question, what do we know about $\langle m_i,n_i \rangle$?

Comment: The problem is that the isomorphism $N^{*}\to N$ can really be any isomorphism. In the language of category theory, it is not "natural." And the basis of $N$ highly depends on that isomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer the second part of my own question, following from the answer of @57Jimmy. Suppose we have a basis $\{m_1,...,m_d\}$, then this corresponds to a basis $\{n_1,..,n_d\}$ such that $\langle m_i,n_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$. So for any $n \in N$ such that $n=\sum a_j n_j$ we see that $\langle m_i,n \rangle = a_i$. Suppose now we have $R$-linear operators $T_N$ on $N$, and $T_M$ on $M$ that are compatible with the pairing as defined in the question, and the basis elements $\{m_1,..,m_d\}$ are eigenvectors for $T_M$, so that $T_M(m_i)=\lambda_i m_i$. Then for any basis element $n_i$, such that $T_N(n_i)=\sum a_j n_j$, we see that:
\begin{align*}
\lambda_i = \lambda_i \langle m_i,n_i \rangle = \langle T_M (m_i),n_i\rangle = \langle m_i,T_N(n_i) \rangle = a_i
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
0 = \lambda_j \langle m_j,n_i \rangle = \langle T_M (m_j),n_i\rangle = \langle m_j,T_N(n_i) \rangle = a_j
\end{align*}
therefore $T_N(n_i)=\lambda_i n_i$, so $n_i$ is an eigenvector.

Answer (score 1):

Given a basis $\{n_1,...,n_d\}$ of a vector space $N$, the dual basis is by definition the basis $\{n_1^*,...,n_d^*\}$ of $N^*$ defined by $n_i^*(n_j)=\delta_{ij}.$ Hence for a basis $\{m_1,...,m_d\}$ of $M$ we get a basis $\{n_1^*,...,n_d^*\}$ of $N^*$ given by $n_i^*:=\Phi_1(m_i)$ and then we define the corresponding basis $\{n_1,...,n_d\}$ of $N$ by the condition $n_i^*(n_j)=\delta_{ij},$ which is equivalent to $\langle m_i,n_j \rangle=\delta_{ij}.$ This should answer your general question, can you then specify to your concrete problem?

Comment: For the concrete problem: what do you mean by saying that $T$ works on both $M$ and $N$? How is $T$ defined?

Comment: I tried to specify the problem. Actually I am working with Hecke operators on the pairing between cusp forms for $\Gamma_0(N)$ and the first homology group over $X_0(N)$, but I hoped to find a more general result.

Comment: I think I found the answer. What I needed was all basis elements of $M$ to be eigenvectors for $T_M$. The only thing I am wondering about your explanation: How do we know, given this basis $\langle n_1^*,..n_d^* \rangle$, that there exists a basis $\langle n_1,..,n_d \rangle$ such that $n_i^*(n_j)=\delta_{ij}$? I can see that for every $n_i^*$ you can find elements such that $n_i^*(n_i)=1$, but how do you provide that these elements are 0 under the other maps?

Comment: $N$ is canonically isomorphic to $N^{**}$ via $\Psi: n \mapsto (\Psi(n): \phi \mapsto \phi(n))$. The image of a basis of $N$ is the dual basis of the dual basis: $n_i^{**}(n_j^*) = \delta_{ij} = n_j^*(n_i) = \Psi(n_i)(n_j^*)$, hence $n_i^{**}=\Psi(n_i)$. So starting from $N^*$ you can find the dual basis in $N^{**}$ and map back to $N$ via the isomorphism $\Psi$. Or just notice that all the $n_j^*$ have $d-1$ dimensional kernels that cannot overlap completely, so choose a basis from the complements of the kernels and then scale it so that you get $1$ and not another real number.

Comment: Your completed answer above looks good to me!